# Kubernetes on TLS secured etcd

Tags: security, ssl, kubernetes, etcd

Running CoreOS, etcd is not secured by default. To secure it I can use TLS, which adds a level of complexity I'm willing to work on.

Now, is Kubernetes able to use a TLS secured etcd cluster?

In the config for the kubelet and various pods, Kubernetes passes the etcd endpoints as parameters, so they require etcd and will need the certificates to talk to it if it is secured. 
If Kubernetes supports TLS connection to etcd, how does it get configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

digging further and asking on the github project, I was directed towards this post that I hope answers the question:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-containers/bTfEcRQ3N28/discussion

In short the config file should look like:

```
{
  "cluster": {
    "machines": [
          "https://kube-master.internal:2379",
          "https://kube-minion1.internal:2379",
          "https://kube-minion2.internal:2379"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "certFile": "/etc/etcd/kube-master.internal.pem",
    "keyFile": "/etc/etcd/kube-master.internal.key",
    "caCertFiles": [ "/etc/etcd/kubecluster-ca.pem" ],
    "consistency": "STRONG_CONSISTENCY"
  }
}
```

Haven't tried yet but will asap.

Comment: since a lottle bit now you need to use the flags on etcd. see the etcd api doc

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kubernetes-users/$20"consistency"$3A$20"STRONG_CONSISTENCY"|sort:date/kubernetes-users/bTfEcRQ3N28/yEQJjVL4AAAJ

Answer (score 3):

The API server is the only component that speaks directly to etcd. When starting the API server, you can pass a `--etcd-config=/path/to/client/config` parameter instead of just pointing to an unsecured etcd server with `--etcd-server`

In that config file, you would specify the etcd servers, along with the client credentials (cert/key) to use to connect.

The format is that expected by the go-etcd client NewClientFromFile function, which expects a JSON serialization of the [Client](https://github.com/coreos/go-etcd/blob/de3514f25635bbfb024fdaf2a8d5f67378492675/etcd/client.go#L50) struct, specifically the `config` and `cluster` keys

Comment: thanks... do you have some link for the docs on writing this config file? what's the format and keys to use. cert/key is kinda vague.

Comment: PS: PodMaster also references --etcd-servers

Comment: I wasn't aware of that... podmaster isn't in the core repository... I opened an issue to make it behave the same as the api server (https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/133)

Comment: Thanks. Btw, do you know of a good document explaining what part does what exactly. (Api server, proxy, podmaster, kubelet, controller manager, scheduler...)I am still confused. Thanks

Comment: And if you're going to configure kubernetes with DNS - be aware that kube2sky does not support etcd TLS.